# Google AdWords API - AdGroupAdError CANNOT_CREATE_DEPRECATED_ADS

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm using Google AdWords Python SDK to create [ResponsiveDisplayAd](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/AdGroupAdService.ResponsiveDisplayAd)s. My code is like below.

```
adgroup_ad_service = adwords_client.GetService(
    service_name = "AdGroupAdService",
    version = "v201809"
)

operations = [{
    'operator': 'ADD',
    'operand': {
        'xsi_type': 'AdGroupAd',
        'adGroupId': '<AD_GROUP_ID>',
        'ad': {
            'xsi_type': 'ResponsiveDisplayAd',
            'marketingImage': {
                'mediaId': '<MEDIA_ID>'
            },
            'shortHeadline': 'Short Headline',
            'longHeadline': 'This is a very long headline',
            'description': 'This is a description',
            'businessName': 'Test Business Name',
            'finalUrls': ['https://www.google.com'],
            'squareMarketingImage': {
                'mediaId': '<MEDIA_ID>'
            }
        },
        'status': 'PAUSED'
    }
}]

ads_response = adgroup_ad_service.mutate(operations)

print("AD RESPONSE : {}".format(ads_response))
```

But It's giving me, `AdGroupAdError.CANNOT_CREATE_DEPRECATED_ADS`.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/AdGroupAdService.AdGroupAdError) it describe this error as `An ad of this type is deprecated and cannot be created. Only deletions are permitted.`.

But in documentation of the [AdGroupAd](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/AdGroupAdService.AdGroupAd) **ResponsiveDisplayAd**, is one of the accepted Ad types.

So it would be great if someone can point me a direction to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **AddMultiAssetResponsiveDisplayAd**  instead.
Same result in a different way.
Hope you can make it like i did.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm now using **AddMultiAssetResponsiveDisplayAd ** instead of **ResponsiveDisplayAd**. And if someone facing the same issue here, I would recommend to go straight into using **AddMultiAssetResponsiveDisplayAd ** without troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Google moved from REsponsiveDisplayAd. That's why  I asked you to go with this. Some exceptions can be solved. but some should be avoided.